# Eclipse: Access Target Definition by code

Tags: eclipse, repository, p2, target-platform

I use Eclipse with a target platform. The target definition is an xml-file listing the P2-repositories with the corresponding features. I know how to check and modify the target definition via the Eclipse IDE.

I am wondering whether it's possible to load the target definition via Java code? In other words: is there a way to write a program that loads the (active) target definition?

Once I have access to the target definition, I would like to extract the P2-repositories and perform some P2QL queries on them. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to even access the target definition by code...

Comment: Eclipse PDE has lots of code for this. Search the Eclipse help for things like `ITargetPlatformService` and `ITargetDefinition`

Comment: https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/reference/api/overview-summary.html?cp=4_3_10

Comment: This project is doing exactly that … https://github.com/irbull/p2diff